# missing instances in sqllocaldb info

Tags: sql

I'm trying to understand the difference of these.  I believe these are called NAMED INSTANCES.  Now I'm trying to SHARE The db with sqllocaldb.  But when I type in "sqllocaldb info", I only see MSSQLSERVER in the list.  Why can't I see all 3 instances?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

sqllocaldb info creates LOCAL instance of database, while this what you can see is a NETWORK (or just normal) instance.

Difference is that LOCAL instance is available only to processes running on the same machine, while to other are available to other machines within network.

Each instance is like a separate server software running on the same machine. It has many advantages, like resource governing, security, etc.

Comment: I'm still confused.  I can connect to IPSINSTANCE2/myDbName successfully via SSMS.  Now when I publish a locally hosted site on a different pc, Site Pc cannot connect to Sql pc anymore.  From what I understand I have to create a SHARE of that localdb.  I'm completely lost here